# I want to change the specific prediction of my CNN-model to a probability

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I trained a model to categorize pictures in two different types. Everything is working
quite good, but my Model can only do a specific prediction (1 or 0 in my case), but I am interested to have a prediction which is more like a probability (For example 90% 1 and 10% 0).
Where is the part of my code which I should change now? Is it something with the sigmoid function in the end which decides if its 1 or 0? Help would be nice. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import regularizers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

from utils import DataGenerator, PATH

train_path = 'Dataset/train'
valid_path = 'Dataset/valid'
test_path = 'Dataset/test'

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=(640, 640, 1), padding='same', activation='relu',
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
                 bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
                 bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
                 bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(6, 6)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu',
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4)))
print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

datagen = DataGenerator()
datagen.load_data()

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(batch_size=batch_size), epochs=epochs, validation_data=datagen.get_validation_data(),
                    callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir=PATH+'/tensorboard')])

#model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
model.save('second_try')
```

If I try to get a picture in my model like this:

```
path = 'train/clean/picturenumber2'  
def prepare(filepath):   
  IMG_SIZE = 640    
  img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)    
  new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))   
  return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1) 

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('second_try') 
prediction = model.predict(prepare(path))
print(prediction)
```

I just get an output like this: `[[1.]]` Also if I put in a list with multiple pictures. The prediction itself seems to be working.

Comment: What you model outputs is already the probability of the positive class.

Comment: So far, when I load a new image with: ```model = tf.keras.models.load_model('second_try') prediction = model.predict(prepare(files)) ``` I only get back a 1 or a 0. Prepare is a function which just gives the images the right shape and put it into a numpy array

Comment: try softmax instead of sigmoid

Comment: It should produce output between 0 and 1. I've checked your code and changed it a little and tested on MNIST and got values like `0.49863368` in the output. So as @Dr.Snoopy said your code should be fine and is fine

Comment: Thanks for the Information. Maybe I am doing something wrong in the part where a use my Model for new pictures

Comment: Please do **not** post code in the comments - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your post instead.

Comment: @clanky1997 - You may want to revisit your kernel_size to max_pool size ratio.  Your kernel_size is smaller than your max_pool size for every conv/pool combo.  My intuition is that this NN can only detect textures and locations of textures, but because a kernel_size 3x3 with max_pool of 5x5 destructively ignores 16 of 25 inputs.  Low level noise in the training will probably demonstrate your NNs weakness.  Your network may simply be overfit to the train and test texture.

Answer (score 2):

short answer :
change **sigmoid** activation function in the last layer to **softmax**

why ?

because sigmoid output range is 0.0 to 1.0, so to make a meaningful interpretation of this output, you choose an appropriate threshold above which represents the positive class and anything below as negative class.(for a binary classification problem)

even softmax has the same output range but the difference being its outputs are **normalized class probabilities** more on that [here](https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/), so if your model outputs 0.99 on any given input, then it can be interpreted as the model is 99.0% confident that it is a positive class and 0.1% confident that it belongs to a negative class.

update :
as @amin suggested, if you need normalized probabilities you should do couple more changes for it to work.

1. modify your data generator to output 2 classes/labels instead of one.
2. change last Dense layer from 1 node to 2 nodes.

Comment: Softmax should be used when your output has more than one neuron (look at the formula and you'll understand why), so I think it's not appropriate for this question

Comment: @amin thanks for informing, i forgot the summation in denominator !